# JS iterate array items and group them in new array by property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects

```
    listOfItems: any[] = [
      {text: 'Hola', group: 'espanian'},
      {text: 'Hello', group: 'english'},
      {text: 'How are you', group: 'english'},
      {text: 'Tere', group: 'estonian'},
    ]
```

I would like to iterate over an array and create another array with categorized objects

```
    groups: any[] = [
    [
      { name: 'english', 
        items: [
           {text: 'Hello', group: 'english'},
           {text: 'How are you', group: 'english'},
        ]
      },
      { name: 'espanian', 
        items: [
           {text: 'Hola', group: 'espanian'}
        ]
      },
      { name: 'estonian', 
        items: [
           {text: 'Tere', group: 'estonian'}
        ]
      },
    ]
```

What is the most dynamic way to do it?
The number of groups could be over 30, so I would like to avoid doing if or equals checks inside the loop

I mean dynamic - is basically without any explicit checks
like item.group = 'english'

I have tried to achieve something similar with

```
      let result: any = [];
      this.listOfItems.forEach(p => {
        var key = p.group;
        result[key] = result[key] || [];
        result[key].push(p);
      })
```

however the result is not exactly what I am looking for

```
[
   {'english': [
             {text: 'Hello', group: 'english'},
             {text: 'How are you', group: 'english'},
            ]
   }, 
   {'espanian': [
             {text: 'Hola', group: 'espanian'},
            ]
   },
]
```

Comment: What does "most dynamic way" mean? Could you explain it a bit? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @LazarNikolic answered your question in my post. I hope it makes it clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Why `any[]`?
2. Maps are really great for these types of data manipulations. Check it out:

```
interface Item {
    text: string;
    group: string;
}

interface Categorized {
    name: string;
    items: Item[];
}

const itemList: Item[] = [
    { text: 'Hola', group: 'espanian' },
    { text: 'Hello', group: 'english' },
    { text: 'How are you', group: 'english' },
    { text: 'Tere', group: 'estonian' },
];

const categorize = (list: Item[]): Categorized[] => {
    const map: Record<string, Categorized> = {};

    list.forEach((item) => {
        if (!map[item.group]) {
            map[item.group] = { name: item.group, items: [item] };
            return;
        }

        map[item.group].items.push(item);
    });

    return Object.values(map);
};

console.log(categorize(itemList));
```

We're only using one loop.

Compiled:

```js
var itemList = [
    { text: 'Hola', group: 'espanian' },
    { text: 'Hello', group: 'english' },
    { text: 'How are you', group: 'english' },
    { text: 'Tere', group: 'estonian' },
];
var categorize = function (list) {
    var map = {};
    list.forEach(function (item) {
        if (!map[item.group]) {
            map[item.group] = { name: item.group, items: [item] };
            return;
        }
        map[item.group].items.push(item);
    });
    return Object.values(map);
};
console.log(categorize(itemList));
```

Comment: But you're not using a `map` and this could be replaced with a `reduce`

Comment: @locrizak It could be replaced with a `reduce`. And a JS object is just a `map` under the hood, so I am technically using a map here.

Comment: `Map` and a plain object are not the same thing and you are not using a `Map` here either. Someone viewing this answer may not know they are the same concept but different syntax and functionality. You should be more clear and concise when answering questions.

Comment: @locrizak I'm not saying that a JavaScript `Map` and a JavaScript object are the same exact thing. I am saying that a JavaScript object is a "map"/"hash" data structure, because that's exactly what it is.

Comment: But they are different data structures. Other than being stored as `key: value` and having prototypes, they do different things and have different data structures. In this case calling `map.size()` will not work because it is an object. Saying `Maps are really great for these types of data manipulations` is maybe a correct statement (depending on the team) but you didn't actually use a map.

Comment: @locrizak Once again, a JavaScript object is a map data structure. Therefore, I did use a map. I’m not talking about the “Map” constructor. I’m talking about map, as a data structure that can be seen in any other programming language. Nobody is arguing with the fact that JS Object and Map have different prototypes or that they are different. They are definitely different.

Answer (score 4):

`Array.reduce` implementation.

```js
const listOfItems = [
  { text: 'Hola', group: 'espanian' },
  { text: 'Hello', group: 'english' },
  { text: 'How are you', group: 'english' },
  { text: 'Tere', group: 'estonian' },
];

const output = listOfItems.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const matchItem = acc.find(item => item.name === curr.group);
  if (matchItem) {
    matchItem.items.push(curr);
  } else {
    acc.push({
      name: curr.group,
      items: [curr]
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

For those who are concerned about double loop, you can achieve the above one with a single loop using.

```js
const listOfItems = [
  { text: 'Hola', group: 'espanian' },
  { text: 'Hello', group: 'english' },
  { text: 'How are you', group: 'english' },
  { text: 'Tere', group: 'estonian' },
];

const output = listOfItems.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.group] ? acc[curr.group].items.push(curr) : acc[curr.group] = {
    name: curr.group,
    items: [curr]
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(output));
```

Comment: With this you're using two loops though :( .find() is also a loop. Nested loops aren't necessary here. Check my solution, or Amaarrockz

Comment: @mstephen19 This is only the presentation of the core logic. If you want to see an implementation with single loop, you can check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code

```
const modifiedList = listOfItems.reduce((acc, item) => {
 if(!acc[item.group]) acc[item.group]=[item];
 else acc[item.group].push(item);
 return acc;
}, {});
let newList = [];
for(let item in modifiedList) {
 newList.push({
   name: item,
   items: modifiedList[item]
 })
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Same thing as mine, but more concise. Nice!!!!

Comment: Incorrect usage of `Array.reduce`. Run this in local and check the console errors.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const listOfItems = [
    {text: 'Hola', group: 'espanian'},
    {text: 'Hello', group: 'english'},
    {text: 'How are you', group: 'english'},
    {text: 'Tere', group: 'estonian'},
]

const groups = listOfItems.reduce((acc, {text, group}) => {
    if(!acc[group]) {
        acc[group] = {name: group, items: []}
    }
    acc[group].items.push({text, group})
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(groups));
```